# Can we enable Save Card option with Pay By Link [POST] method

Tags: global-payments-api

I'm working on Global Payments system and trying to achieve Pay By Link http post method to generate the link and share with customer to pay at their convenient time. In the sandbox url below request body is working fine.

```
{
  "SHA1HASH": "606ab12bb09f5e68b1d72ce26622650d485583fd",
  "TIMESTAMP": "20210612042252",
  "MERCHANT_ID": "somehotel",
  "ACCOUNT": "internet",
  "ORDER_ID": "5ef1c1ce6da546069998744bdce3d8c9",
  "AMOUNT": "2000",
  "CURRENCY": "EUR",
  "AUTO_SETTLE_FLAG": "1",
  "COMMENT1": "Email Channel",
  "HPP_VERSION": "2",
  "HPP_LANG": "en",
  "HPP_CUSTOMER_EMAIL": "somebody@gmail.com",
  "HPP_CUSTOMER_PHONENUMBER_MOBILE": "91|9999999999",
  "HPP_BILLING_STREET1": "Flat 123",
  "HPP_BILLING_STREET2": "House 456",
  "HPP_BILLING_STREET3": "Unit 4",
  "HPP_BILLING_CITY": "Halifax",
  "HPP_BILLING_POSTALCODE": "W5 9HR",
  "HPP_BILLING_COUNTRY": "826",
  "HPP_SHIPPING_STREET1": "Apartment 852",
  "HPP_SHIPPING_STREET2": "Complex 741",
  "HPP_SHIPPING_STREET3": "House 963",
  "HPP_SHIPPING_CITY": "Chicago",
  "HPP_SHIPPING_STATE": "IL",
  "HPP_SHIPPING_POSTALCODE": "50001",
  "HPP_SHIPPING_COUNTRY": "840",
  "HPP_ADDRESS_MATCH_INDICATOR": "FALSE",
  "HPP_CHALLENGE_REQUEST_INDICATOR": "NO_PREFERENCE",
  "BILLING_CODE": "59|123",
  "BILLING_CO": "GB",
  "SHIPPING_CODE": "50001|Apartment 852",
  "SHIPPING_CO": "US",
  "CUST_NUM": "6e027928-c477-4689-a45f-4e138a1f208a",
  "VAR_REF": "Acme Corporation",
  "PROD_ID": "SKU1000054",
  "MERCHANT_RESPONSE_URL": "https://www.example.com/responseUrl",
  "SUPPLEMENTARY_DATA": "Custom Value"
}
```

Is there a way to enable Save Card option. I tried providing the below flags as seen on another payment reference, but the response started giving hash error.

### Request Body included below

```
  "CARD_STORAGE_ENABLE": "1",
  "OFFER_SAVE_CARD": "1",
  "PAYER_EXIST": "0",
  "PAYER_REF": "376a2598-412d-4805-9f47-c177d5605853",
  "PMT_REF": "ca46344d-4292-47dc-9ced-e8a42ce66977",
```

### And the response from server

```
{
    "resultCode":508,
    "internalErrorCode":61000,
    "errorMessage":"Incorrect hash. Please check your code and the Developers Documentation."
}
```

Is this a restriction by purpose or are we passing wrong flags? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

These are the two sections from the developer portal describing how to generate the hash:

Card Payments: https://developer.globalpay.com/hpp/card-payments#generate-hash

Card Storage: https://developer.globalpay.com/hpp/card-storage#generate-hash